# White dots on pizza or focaccia after baking

Tags: baking, bread, dough, pizza, italian-cuisine

Sometimes I prepare a pizza dough that is a "direct" knead, no fancy preparations, works with all-purpose flour, rises in a couple of hours with regular yeast, about 70% hydration, olive oil inside.
It can be refrigerated after you roll out the dough if you want to bake it after some hours, with or without tomato sauce topping (I add the mozzarella later after tests in my oven).

In most cases, the fridge rest is about 18 hours. Sometimes I take the dish out about one hour before baking, sometimes I bake it right away (assume the oven is in temperature, about 250C).

No matter whether I let it rest before baking, I notice some white spots in areas that don't have any topping.

I thought it was about the thermic shock of going from the fridge to the oven, but since it happens in all cases I really don't see the pattern. What can it be?

Here is a picture of the final product after taking it out of the fridge where it had been for about 20 hours and a couple of hours at room temperature before baking.
[image]

Comment: Do you sprinkle salt at any point before baking?

Comment: Not additionally but salt is in bakers percentage about 3%

Comment: Any chance you have a photo?

Comment: original question edited with picture

Comment: Is there any texture to the spots?  Are they actually little tiny bumps / bubbles, or are they smooth with the surrounding area?

Comment: I dont know what exactly creates these spots but I occasionally noticed a smiliar surface texture on some comercially bought turkish flatbread and especially börek. So at least this indicates these spots are nothing to wory about. My assumption would be that the combination of wheat dough and oil is the key to the phenomen.

Comment: they are tiny bumps that I know not to make the product unsafe. I just wonder why the same recipe baked right away doesn't develop them.